# How to disable print option of QLPreviewController in the Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, qlpreviewcontroller

In my Xamarin.Froms application, on the iOS side, I open the files as preview with the help of QLPreviewController. When I open the preview and press the share button, the print option appears. (As in the picture below.)
[image]

How can I turn this off?
When I searched, it says that the RightBarButtonItem value can be set enabled false or null. But this directly closes the share button. I want the share button to remain open but the print option to be turned off. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you? Since all the other share options remain available, you won't be able to prevent printing anyway.

Comment: I am integrating airwatch sdk into my application. Printing true/false value comes with dlp rules of airwatch sdk. I can get this rule in my app. If this rule is false, I think I should close the places where I can trigger the print operation. That's why I'm trying to do this. DLP-Printing: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workspace-ONE-UEM/services/AirWatch-Container/GUID-AWT-APPENDIX-SDK-SETTINGS-MATRIX.html

Comment: I was thinking of doing this for the rule that comes in the airwatch sdk as I mentioned in the previous message. However, with the airwatch sdk integration, I was able to remove the print option without making any changes to the QLPreviewController. That's why I don't need it anymore. Thanks.